# Bootstrap 4 Loading Spinner in button

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap 4 loading spinner in button as in 
[Bootstrap Spinners](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/spinners/#buttons).

Below is what I'm doing in code

**my.html**

```
<form class="form-inline" id="topicForm" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="inputTopic" name="topic" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Topic of interest" required autofocus/>
  <button type="button" id="btnFetch" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**my.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
      // load data via AJAX
      fetch_data($("#inputTopic").val());
      // disable button
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      // add spinner to button
      $(this).html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...`
      );
    });
});
```

This works except that the spinner as shown in bootstrap doc is not showing up. The button text is changing to `Loading...` as expected. Wanted to know what is that I'm not doing right to the spinner inside the button.

**[Code Pen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwJoQb)**

Comment: Bootstrap spinners.css is included?

Comment: the only css included is `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: seems like it doesn't contain spinner css - I just done a search in above CSS

Comment: Have you tried it? One g was extra in Loadingg...

Comment: I don’t see an extra ‘g’ and also that shouldn’t matter. Where do I get ‘spinners.css’ from ?

Comment: You can just try below code and CSS- It will work fine. @user3206440

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have to add Bootstrap 4.2.1 for this code while you are using 4.0

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
      // disable button
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      // add spinner to button
      $(this).html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Loading...`
      );
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="margin:3em;">
  <form class="form-inline" id="topicForm" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="inputTopic" name="topic" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Topic of interest" required autofocus/>
    <button type="button" id="btnFetch" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you add a recover script after some timeout?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the spinner after a specific time or just by calling some method or removing some css, etc. Basically I am looking for starting the spinner on button click and then when some processing finishes I want to stop the spinner.

Comment: Experienced the same issue while using `django-bootstrap4==1.0.1` (had Bootrtrap v4.1.1). Migration to `django-bootstrap4==1.1.1` upgraded Bootstrap version to 4.3.1 and spinners started working instant. Very useful answer.

Comment: Strangely, this works fine for me on Firefox but it does not on Chrome. On Chrome, the button just keeps spinning forever but the form is never really submitted - or at least the new page is not loaded.

Comment: I having same issue that @CGFoX.

Edit

Add $("#form-id").submit();  after $(this).html(.....

Comment: This is working as expected. Anyone know how I can make the button obey the required attribute? Because when you click even though the input is required the spinner gets activated anyways.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me. It stores the original text/html as an attribute & restores it from there.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
           var $this = $(this);
           
           //Call Button Loading Function
           BtnLoading($this);
    
           //Call Button Reset Function after AJAX or your code execution
           BtnReset($this);
        });
    });
    
    function BtnLoading(elem) {
        $(elem).attr("data-original-text", $(elem).html());
        $(elem).prop("disabled", true);
        $(elem).html('<i class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></i> Loading...');
    }
    
    function BtnReset(elem) {
        $(elem).prop("disabled", false);
        $(elem).html($(elem).attr("data-original-text"));
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems like spinner CSS is not present in the loaded CSS library. Please try below codes

In CSS

```
    @keyframes spinner-border {
      to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    } 
    .spinner-border{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
        border: .25em solid currentColor;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
        animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
    }
    .spinner-border-sm{
        height: 1rem;
        border-width: .2em;
    }
```

In JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnFetch").click(function() {
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loadingg...`
      );
    });
});
```

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXyKwR)

Comment: this worked for me, any clue on why CSS should be added manually on these bootstrap spinner classes?

Comment: please check the version compbatibilities

Answer (score 3):

Could you Try Adding [In head] I added It Worked in your codepen

```
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and this

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying Vinay's Answer to work in my case I simply store the text instead of the html as my original button was being modified on reset.

```
function btnLoading(elem) {
    $(elem).attr("data-original-text", $(elem).text()); // <-use .text() instead of .html()
    $(elem).prop("disabled", true);
    $(elem).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle" aria-hidden="true" role="status"></span> loading...');
}

function btnReset(elem) {
    $(elem).prop("disabled", false);
    $(elem).text($(elem).attr("data-original-text"));
}
```