# Trying to change the span class for a submit button to show bootstrap loading spinner

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a submit button to change to a loading spinner with the text "Loading..." using JavaScript like the image below.

[image]

I'm able to update the innerHTML for the button, but I'm having trouble changing the span class, which controls the actual spinner.

Here is my html for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mx-3" id="submit" onclick="loading()" type="submit">
  <span id="button_span"></span>
  Submit
</button>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
function loading() {
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.innerHTML = "Loading...";
    var span = document.getElementById("button_span");
    span.classList.add("spinner-grow");
    span.classList.add("spinner-grow-sm");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a working pen:
https://codepen.io/cbrown___/pen/dyMKQQb

Using Jquery and Font-awesome.
THere are many ways of doing this, but this is one of them.

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mx-3" id="submit" onclick="loading()" type="submit">
   <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" style="display:none;"></i>
  <span class="btn-text">Submit</span>
</button>
```

.JS

```
function loading() {
  $(".btn .fa-spinner").show();
  $(".btn .btn-text").html("Loading");
  
}
```

Recommend also this solution:
[Bootstrap 4 Loading Spinner in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522830/bootstrap-4-loading-spinner-in-button?rq=1)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  The only change I made was using the grow-spinner instead of the fa-spinner.

Comment: Gave you an upvote. Just use class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" instead of class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" and it will work. :-)

Comment: After trying multiple solutions, yours finally worked. Thank you. Also, if anyone wants to use other animated icons the codes can be found at https://fontawesome.com/v4/examples/. Just make sure to change the spinner code in the ``loading()`` function as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be changing the inner HTML or class of the button. Create a new span that is the loading animation but hidden by default with css prop `display: none`.

When the button get clicked hide the button by dynamically changing the css and show the span the same way. Then whenever the loading is done just flip it back.